# Problem with sender definition in squirrel mail over dovecot installed on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, email, postfix

I recently installed squirrelmail on an ubuntu server, with dovecot installed. It seems to work well, except when I send an e-mail, the receiving party sees the mail as coming from @example.com, i.e the domain name is "example" instead of the real domain name.
I am not sure if this should be configured somewhere in the dovecot, in the squirrelmail configuration or in the postfix. So far I found nothing.

Thanks

Comment: I think you'll get more response on Server Fault--this question is specifically about a server issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to login to Squirrelmail and then set your email and user name details on the Options...Personal Information page:

[image]

There's a plugin you can install that automatically guides a new user to do this - worth installing to avoid this problem...

http://squirrelmail.org/plugins_category.php?category_id=1  "Ask User Info"